# Creating multi language web app with i18n-2 in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization, i18next

I created an express(node.js) website with two language with [i18n-2 module](https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2) and now i have a problem. i was thinking that if i change a new language except default language, all links in my web site will have `/?lang` parameter automatically! i18n-2 will do it or myself have to code this feature?

right now if i add `/?lang=de` by hand, it works but if i back to my websites root, it goes to defalult locale and that parameter removes from the url.

this is my configuration:

```
I18n.expressBind(app, {
   locales: ['en', 'de'],
   defaultLocale: 'en',
   cookieName: 'locale',
   extension: ".json"
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   req.i18n.setLocaleFromQuery();
   req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();

   next();
 });
```

Comment: same problem,  still haven't found the answer

Answer (score 3):

In order to perpetuate the selected language you need to install a package called [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser):

```
npm install --save cookie-parser
```

Then attach it to the Express application as follows:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    cookieParser = require('coookie-parser'),
    i18n2 = require('i18n-2');

app.use(cookieParser());
i18n2.expressBind(app, {
   locales: ['en', 'de'],
   defaultLocale: 'en',
   cookieName: 'locale'
});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.lang) {
    req.i18n.setLocaleFromQuery();
    res.cookie(config.locale.cookie, req.i18n.getLocale());
  } else {
    req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();
  }
  next();
})
```

This way you can change the language through the `lang` query parameter and make it permanent using the cookie storage.